# Transforming an initial value problem into a Volterra integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I transform

$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=f(t,u), \ u(0)=u_0,\ u'(0)=u_1$$
into a Volterra integral equation of the form
$$u(t)=g(t)+\int_{0}^{t} k(t,s)G(s,u(s))ds,\ 0\leq t\leq T$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an initial value problem you can take the linear Taylor polynomial with integral remainder term,
$$
u(t)=u(0)+u'(0)t+\int_0^t(t-s)u''(s)\,ds=u_0+u_1t+\int_0^t(t-s)f(s,u(s))\,ds,
$$
which has the required form of an integral equation.

---

This is the same that you would have gotten when using partial integration to the final double integral,
$$
\int_0^t1\cdot\int_0^sf(\tau,u(\tau))\,d\tau\,ds=\left[s\cdot \int_0^sf(\tau,u(\tau))\,d\tau\right]_0^t-\int_0^t sf(s,u(s))\, ds
$$

---

Of course, you can leave it also in the standard Picard-Voltera integral equation form, that is, the integral equation for the first order system that you obtained on the way, 
$$
\pmatrix{u(t)\\v(t)}=\pmatrix{u(0)\\v(0)}+\int_0^t\pmatrix{v(s)\\f(s,u(s))}\,ds
$$
so that $k(s,t)=1$ and $G(s,\vec u)=\pmatrix{u_2(s)\\f(s,u_1(s))}$.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the answer gave me the suggestion to use the Laplace transform, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform. 
As the table on wikipedia shows, the Laplace transform of the equation is given by
\begin{align}
s^2\mathcal{L}u-su_0-u_1=\mathcal{L}f.
\end{align}
Now you can solve for $\mathcal{L}u$ and transform back using the second large table on wikipedia. The product in the laplace domain will result in a convolution in the time domain, exactly as you would hope for.